# Add checkbox to Date Range Picker Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using https://www.daterangepicker.com/ Date Range Picker in my application to pick start date and end date for my post. I am not sure any of us here have used this Date Range Picker here but wanted to see how can i add an element to this Date Range Picker by JavaScript or JQuery. Basically, we want to give user an ability to select end date indefinitely so i want to add checkbox in date range picker which will say "Unlimited" and When user check this checkbox i will make my daterange picker to select date in far future which will behave as indefinite end date.

One of the approach i have came up with is by catching show.daterangepicker event. Still working on this but thought to take advice from the community here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach by add "checkbox" commonly accepted. however, in my opinion instead of putting in your **daterangepicker**, why not put it outside like linkedin?

[image]

my other opinion, instead of making "**daterangepicker**" to select date in far future, you actually can programmatically decide if the checkbox "checked" then use "**datepicker**" if not then use "**daterangepicker**"